# Optimized select query for two tables with condtions

Tags: sql, join, select, optimization

Dears,

I have a situation where I need to write a single SQL query in order to get the records from one table.
For example say I have two tables, TblParent and TblChild
And I need the records from the TblChild table as below,

```
SELECT * FROM TblParent WHERE condition_1 AND condition_2 AND condition_3: //possible many records

     //for each parent
     SELECT * FROM TblChild WHERE TblChild.fld1 = TblParent.fld1 AND TblChild.fld2 = TblParent.fld2
                              AND TblChild.fld3 > 0 ......
```

Basically I need the TblChild records only but in order to get them I need query TblParent with conditions and for each of them I need to get the relevant TblChild records.

Since I'm new to SQL and not sure about the best method to choose in terms of optimization, please help me write a single query for the above scenario.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT tc.*
FROM TblParent INNER JOIN
     TblChild tc
     ON tc.fld1 = TblParent.fld1 AND 
        tc.fld2 = tc.fld2 AND
        tc.fld3 > 0
WHERE condition_1_on_TblParent AND condition_2_on_TblParent AND condition_3_on_TblParent
```

Comment: Thank You Onkar and Gordon LinOff, this works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Just add your parent-query into the child-query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM TblChild, 
     (SELECT * FROM TblParent WHERE condition_1 AND condition_2 AND condition_3) parents
     WHERE TblChild.fld1 = parents.fld1 
      AND TblChild.fld2 = parents.fld2
      AND TblChild.fld3 > 0 ......
```

Comment: Thank You draz, this is working as expected after adding missing 'AS parents'